# how to Give inputs to Lauterbach script?

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I have  practice script that take password from dialog box and set it to var. I want to modify it instead of taking password from dialog box it take it from command line like entering parameters to script.
I have read the ref but i can't find it out.

Comment: This PRACTICE cheat sheet is very useful: https://www.lauterbach.com/reference_card_web.pdf

Answer (score 3):

You can call a script with parameters by providing the parameters after the file name. Each parameter should be quoted:

```
DO my_script.cmm "<my_parameter1>" "<my_parameter2>"
```

The script can retrieve the parameter like below. In this example the script would fall-back to dialog or error handling if there is no password provided by command line.

```
PRIVATE &password
PARAMETERS &password

IF "&password"==""
(
  ;if no password provided from command line,
  ;then fall back to dialog or error handling.
)

PRINT "Password: &password"
ENDDO
```